# How to optimize a sorting / timestamp script for Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm still pretty new to scripts in Google Sheets and I guess what I build here is somewhat not very optimized .. but it works (in most cases).

My goal is to have a script (onEdit) which automatically adds a timestamp (for tasks from new deadline / new none-deadline) in column R and sorts tasks based on a status set in column G (completed, escalation to berlin or requested data) of my spreadsheet into the corresponding tabs.

The problem is that the script does not react some times, so tasks are not getting moved and no timestamp is added. I assume, because to many people are triggering the script at the same time.

I currently have the below stated script in a single project. Is there anything I can do to improve this and have it running more smoothly?

```
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //NEW DEADLINES -- START

    if(s.getName() == "New Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Completed") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "New Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Escalation to Berlin") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Escalation to Berlin");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "New Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Requested Data") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requested Data");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    //SORTING NEW DEADLINES END

  //NEW DEADLINES -- END

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //NEW NON DEADLINES -- START

    if(s.getName() == "New None-Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Completed") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "New None-Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Escalation to Berlin") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Escalation to Berlin");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "New None-Deadlines" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Requested Data") 

    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 11);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requested Data");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

  //NEW NON DEADLINES -- END

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //SORTING COMPLETED -- START

    if(s.getName() == "Completed" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Escalation to Berlin") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Escalation to Berlin");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Completed" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Requested Data") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requested Data");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

  //SORTING COMPLETED -- END

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //SORTING ESCALATION TO BERLIN -- START

    if(s.getName() == "Escalation to Berlin" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Completed") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }

    if(s.getName() == "Escalation to Berlin" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Requested Data") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Requested Data");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }


  //SORTING ESCALATION TO BERLIN -- END

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  //SORTING Requested Data -- START

    if(s.getName() == "Requested Data" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Completed") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }  

    if(s.getName() == "Requested Data" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Escalation To Berlin") 

    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Escalation To Berlin");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(row);
    }  

  //SORTING Requested Data *New -- END
  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this but something like this should work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');//debug
  const tshts = ["Completed", "Escalation to Berlin", "Requested Data"];
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = tshts.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName() == "New Deadlines" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && ~idx) {
    e.source.toast('flag1');//dubug
    e.range.offset(0, 11).setValue(new Date());
    const tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(tshts[idx]);
    const tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the quick reply :). I added const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); under e.source.toast('entry');//debug, because it was not moving the rows to the corresponding tabs in the sheet :). Other than that, it works pretty good. Could you explain what e.source.toast('flag1');//debug is used for? I don't get it.

Comment: @Stekiro https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg

Comment: e.source is the same thing and getActiveSpreadsheet. I forgot to put that in.  The toast method is just a tool I use to debug things.  But I didn't actually debug this code because I never tested it.

Comment: Actually it's not actually the same thing.  One thing that's different about it is that it is the pointer to the spreadsheet not a function to retrieve so it's much faster.